# How can I identify the current depth level of a jquery mobile expanded list?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, expandablelistview

So I've created some nested lists with jquery mobile that are collapsible.  I have working buttons for 'collapse all' and 'expand all.'  I also need buttons for 'collapse some' and 'expand some' that affect only the current deepest level. When you click one of these two buttons, a loop should run that sets the `current_depth` variable to the deepest expanded level.  I'm trying to find a way to identify the current level depth, so that I can use the built in 'collapse' or 'expand' commands on that level.  Normally I would do this with a for loop, like I did for the `max_depth`, but I don't know what identifier to check for to see if the level is open or closed.  Does anyone know what identifiers jquery mobile adds to an expanded or collapsed list?  My first instinct was a `data-collapsed="true"` attribute...but I'm not sure. Functionality wise, everything I've written works, I just need some sort of identifier to distinguish between an expanded and a collapsed element in jquery mobile.  Here's the code I've got so far.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
    <title>Table of Contents</title> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
    </meta>    
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        //Variable to track depth and find max depth
        var current_depth=1;
        var max_depth
        for(i=1;i<=10;i++) {
         if($('ul').hasClass('depth-'+i))
         {
             max_depth = i;
         }
        };

        //Button to expand all links
        $('#openAll').click(function () {
            $('.expandable').trigger('expand');
            current_depth=max_depth;
            alert(max_depth);
        });
        //Button to close all links
        $('#closeAll').click(function () {
            $('.expandable').trigger('collapse');
        });
        //Button to expand current level
        //This Code likely has errors, I'm trying to find a way to identify the current level
        $('#openSome').click(function() {
           for(i=1;i<=10;i++){  
            if($('ul.depth-'+i+'[data-collapsed="true"]').length() !== 0) 
            {
             current_depth=i;
            }
           };
            $('.depth-'+current_depth).trigger('expand');
            alert(current_depth);
        });
        //Button to collapse current level
        $('#closeSome').click(function() {
            $('.depth-'+current_depth).trigger('collapse');
        });
    });
</script>
</head> 
<body> 
    <!--Define global click butons-->
    <button data-role="button" id="openAll"> Expand All</button>
    <button data-role="button" id="openSome"> Expand Some</button>
    <button data-role="button" id="closeAll"> Collapse All</button>
    <button data-role="button" id="closeSome"> Collapse Some</button>


    <!-- Create Sample Link Structure -->
    <div data-role="collapsible" data-theme="b" class="expandable depth-1">
        <h3>Chapter 1</h3>
        <ul data-role="collapsible" data-mini="true" class="expandable depth-2">
            <h3> Section 1 </h3>
            I'm the collapsible set content for section 1.
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div data-role="collapsible" data-theme="b" class="expandable depth-1">
        <h3>Chapter 2</h3>
        <ul data-role="collapsible" data-mini="true" class="expandable depth-2">
            <h3> Section 1 </h3>
            I'm the collapsible set content for section 1.
        </ul>
    </div>    
</body>
```

Comment: is this what you're looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/VXHzH/

Comment: `.ui-collapsible-collapsed` class is added to collapsed elements, you can use it as an identifier as in my demo above.

Comment: It seems to be on the right track.  I didn't realize it was a class that was added. That's a tremendous help thank you!

Comment: Any idea why this doesn't work for the very top level?

Comment: it does work for the top level with selector `div [data-role=collapsible]` and `ul [data-role=collapsible]` for children. *Note*: Dont use `.ready()` in jQM, use jQM events.

Comment: @Omar ji pls make this as an answer. It might help other people later.

Comment: youre welcome :) a lot of  your answers go into comments. you give very good answers to the jQM community but they wont show up in google unless otherwise you make it as an answer. no offense meant..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery Mobile adds `.ui-collapsible-collapsed` to collapsed div, use it to identify whether a div is collapsed or not.

Note that parent collapsible is a *div* and children collapsibles are *ul*. Use `div [data-role=collapsible]` and `ul [data-role=collapsible]` selectors to access them.

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/VXHzH/)**